# How do you run wine in Alpine Linux?

Tags: software-installation, wine, alpine-linux

I installed the wine package but it didn't work:

```
apk update && apk add wine && wine
/bin/sh: wine: not found
```

Comment: Any output from those initial commands?

Comment: If the `apk update` and `apk add wine` appear to have worked, try logging out and logging in again, and then running ``wine``.

Comment: Using `apk info -L wine | grep usr/bin` on my system, I see a number of wine binaries in that package, one is called `wine64`.  Do you have a `wine64` or `wine32` on your system?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try running `wine64`?
On my environment I've done:

```bsh
apk update && apk add wine && ln -s /usr/bin/wine64 /usr/bin/wine
```

Comment: tl;dr: in alpine x86_64, where the `wine` package is just 64-bit wine, there is no `wine` convenience symlink, you need to use e.g. `wine64`, or do something else like run it in an `x86` chroot

Answer (score 1):

Installing wine is fine your computer will now interpret .exe files. You still need a frontend GUI like PlayonLinux in order to actualy do much of anything as far as installing games and the like. If no package is available you will need to install from source. You will need build essentials and some other libraries to make and install the source. The info required to do this will be in the readme in the folder created after extracting.